# Can't compact an access MDB

Tags: ms-access

I have a client with a reaaally old MDB **which we didn't make and they can't contact the guy who did it** and recently it started showing the error:

```
Cannot open database “. It may not be a database 
that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt.
```

Even when I try to **export all the tables** it just keep showing the same error and **if I try to Compact and Repair I get the error that I don't have permission to do so**. I have tried with every single user on the computer. If I restore the previous version all new data will be lost and will just happen again eventually as it doesn't let me compact either and even if I try creating a new database or table in another database, **it doesn't let me import the data into it**.
**I can read all the tables but can't even copy that information**. I'm at a loss of what to do and they asked me to have it for tomorrow.

I will be thankful for any tip you can give me for solving this error

**Edit:**

I have tried opening the file with a newer access to see if I can compact and it doesn't let me enter with any user even though the MDW is the same

Comment: Really old, is that 2.0, 95, or 97?

Comment: @Gustav Office 2000

Comment: Sounds like user-level security, a long-deprecated technique for securing Access databases. You should remove that asap. See [Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-or-change-access-2003-user-level-security-in-access-2007-or-higher-0c6a10e7-966f-44f4-864e-5d2ef79439fa#bm4) on removing it. Data copying and recovery for databases secured with user-level security is a difficult subject and a bit too broad for SO

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth it doesn't let me save it with that format

Comment: Well, not if you haven't logged in as admin. Are you logged in as admin?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth yes I have

Comment: Well, without you sharing any errors I can't help.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I don't get any error, the version is so old that I am unable to save it in another format, as I specified in my edit, if I try opening it with a newer version of Access it doesn't let me with any user. Do you know if I have any way to modify the MDW so I can access with any user? Thanks

Comment: Yes. With A2000 you can modify the mdw. But you still need an admin login to do so (obviously).

Comment: There are tools available from about £10 which allow you export all objects from a MDW (I've had to do it myself in a similar situation), but it if the MDB is as old as you say and it's corrupt it may be unusable now

Comment: @Gustav do you know any possible way to know which user is the correct one? When I looked who created the files it was "Administrator" and I am as it...

Comment: @DarkW1nter I don't want to ask my boss to buy something if I am not sure it will work, do you know if any of those have a trial version? Thanks

Comment: @Spina97 The admin user in user-level security is always named admin. Note that other users might be able to change the password of the admin user if you don't have it.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I do have two admin passwords, the first one is for the user and the second one for the database

Comment: And _admin_ user can change anything, including manage users and groups. _Normal_ users can't do that.

Comment: @Gustav then why even when I login as admin I can't change anything on it and get an error? I would really love to see who did it and how but I can't do that

Comment: Then the database is probably damaged, and you may need [professional assistance](https://www.everythingaccess.com/accessdatabaserepair_info.asp).

Comment: Okay guys I solved it, going to post my answer, thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it! And this is how:

I noticed that the database was about 1'99GB which is almost the size limit of an access database so I just needed to Compact and Repair but it didn't let me because of permissions...

The database had another extra user which we didn't see before for any reason, that user was not even an admin, he was the real user who created the database (even though it kept telling me everywhere that the database was made by the admin and that he was the propietary...)

Since compacting gave me an error that couldn't find the database "Tempmsysaccessobjects", I just had to google it and found the solution in a spanish forum where they recommended creating a new database and importing all old data and with this user it let me do it!

Thank guys for helping!